# Gravity Forms Wordpress: Redirect users role to a specific page

Tags: wordpress, authentication, gravityforms

I added this function from GF, but i don't know how to add another user in the conditional login, can someone help :

```
add_filter( 'gform_user_registration_login_redirect_url', 'gf_redirect_user_role', 10, 2 );
function gf_redirect_user_role( $login_redirect, $sign_on ) {
    GFCommon::log_debug(  __METHOD__ . '(): Running...' );
    if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $sign_on->roles ) ){
        // Redirect users with subcriber role to a specific page.
        $login_redirect = 'https://url';
        GFCommon::log_debug(  __METHOD__ . '(): Redirecting to ' . $login_redirect );
    }
    return $login_redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add an 'else if' to add new conditions

```
add_filter( 'gform_user_registration_login_redirect_url', 'gf_redirect_user_role', 10, 2 );
    function gf_redirect_user_role( $login_redirect, $sign_on ) {
        GFCommon::log_debug(  __METHOD__ . '(): Running...' );
        if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $sign_on->roles ) ){
            // Redirect users with subcriber role to a specific page.
            $login_redirect = 'https://url';
            GFCommon::log_debug(  __METHOD__ . '(): Redirecting to ' . $login_redirect );
        }else if ( in_array( 'customer', $sign_on->roles ) ){
            // Redirect users with customer role to a specific page.
            $login_redirect = 'https://url';
            GFCommon::log_debug(  __METHOD__ . '(): Redirecting to ' . $login_redirect );
        }
        return $login_redirect;
    }
```